# singleton, public, or global variable use

Tags: iphone, global-variables

I have searched and tried every example regarding singleton, public, and global variables in stack overflow on this subject.  I'm making a mistake some where.  I have a settings variable called strIP that is part of a textField and is declared in my secondViewController.h.  I want this variable to used in a class called myWSupdate.m.  It's just one variable I wanna pass it to a connection string.  this compiles correctly but the app crashes on run.  What am I doing incorrectly?

error from complier:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[SecondViewController sharedIP]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x6403c'

secondViewController.h

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
{
UITextField *ipAdd;

NSString *strIP;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *ipAdd;
@property (retain) NSString  *strIP;

+(SecondViewController*)sharedIP;
```

then I call it in myWSupdate.m:

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

/* Implementation of the service */

@implementation myWSupdate

- (id) init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {

        SecondViewController* IP = [[SecondViewController sharedIP]init];
NSLog(@"the test has %@", IP.strIP);
    }
}


@end
```

Comment: I keep getting an error of "use of undeclared identifier 'strIP'. " in myWSupdate.m  what am i missing?

Comment: Because strIP is a member of SecondViewController, and you're trying to access it in a method of myWSupdate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `strIP` belongs to a `SecondViewController`, you need to reference it as part of that object.

How to do that depends on the relationship between `SecondViewController` and `myWSupdate`.  (For example, if the controller creates a `myWSupdate` object, you could pass the variable as part of the init.)

The fact that it's marked public doesn't change the fact that it's an **instance** variable and therefore needs to be used in connection with an **instance** of its class.